# Eclipse 3.6.0 All In One -> subclipse not installing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, eclipse-pdt

I tried installing subclipse  through the "Help->Install New Software" and the URL is http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x but it fails every time. It shows following items

===================================

1. CollabNet Merge Client 3.0.8
2. Subclipse (Required) 1.8.8
3. Subversion Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional) 3.0.0
4. Subversion Client Adapter (required) 1.8.2
5. Subversion JavaHL 1.7.4.1
6. Subversion Revision Graph

===================================

I tried them one by one and only the following could be installed, other four failed:

1. Subversion Client Adapter (required) 1.8.2
2. Subversion JavaHL 1.7.4.1

## One of the errors I get is:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.php, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!

================================================

My environment is as follows:

1. OS: Windows 7 64 Bit
2. Eclipse PDT All in one from http://www.zend.com/en/downloads/thankyou?package=468
3. Subclipse update_1.8.x

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I need at least Subclipse 1.8.8 and CollabNet Merge Client 3.0.8 also in addition to Subversion Client Adapter 1.8.2, Subversion JavaHL 1.7.4.1 that I could install.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar issue with EGit for Eclipse. It seems that it's due to OpenJDK JRE7. The following link worked for me : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360057

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That link pointed me at the right answer which was forcing the vm to the 1.6 JRE... `eclipse -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from your question what the actual problem is.  It sounds like it cannot install the Revision Graph plugin?  That requires the Eclipse GEF/Draw2D plugin, so maybe you do not have that installed.

The Subclipse Core plugin, Client Adapter, JavaHL and Merge Client should all install on any Eclipse version and they are all you need.

There is no need to install the Mylyn integration unless you use Mylyn and want to integrate it.

The Revision Graph plugin is optional.  You will need the GEF plugin installed.

Comment: I noticed the formatting was bad, I've updated the question, please check again.
I could install Subversion Client Adapter 1.8.2, Subversion JavaHL 1.7.4.1 but not the Subclipse 1.8.8
I need this one also at least.

Comment: It looks like a problem in the Eclipse p2 configuration locally.  Does not seem to have anything to do with what you are installing.

Comment: I checked my control panel and I see 3 entries there:
Java 6 update 31, 
Java 7 Update 3, 
Java 7 Update 3 (64-bit)

Is this the issue that I'm having multiple of them?

Comment: I do not believe this would be related to the Java version.  Eclipse maintains a bunch of metadata about what you have installed.  It looks like that metadata has some problems.  It seems to happen a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to see if you can install other Eclipse plugins?  My guess is that trying to install other plugins would show the same error.