# Installing SVN in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I have been using SVN with Eclipse for a long time now, and i've never had any trouble with installation or while using it at all.

However, i now have a new Windows 8, 64-bit machine. I've tried to install the SVN plugin several times and i failed on each occasion. I get the following error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.php, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!
Comparison method violates its general contract!

When installing, it always gets stuck at 25% while trying to retrieve a package.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Check here: [Eclipse 3.6.0 All In One -> subclipse not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298415/eclipse-3-6-0-all-in-one-subclipse-not-installing)

This user got the same error and apparently solved the issue by forcing the VM to use another JRE.